# Pandas - Add Column based on multi part logic check for datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Num         First_Date      Last_Date
20008526    7/3/2013 0:00   7/18/2013 0:00
20008526    7/3/2013 0:00   7/18/2013 0:00
20008526    7/3/2013 0:00   7/18/2013 0:00
20008526    7/3/2013 0:00   7/18/2013 0:00
20008526    7/3/2013 0:00   7/18/2013 0:00
20008526    7/3/2013 0:00   7/18/2013 0:00
20008526    7/3/2013 0:00   7/18/2013 0:00
20008526    7/3/2013 0:00   7/18/2013 0:00
20008526    7/3/2013 0:00   7/18/2013 0:00
20008526    7/3/2013 0:00   7/18/2013 0:00
20008526    7/3/2013 0:00   7/18/2013 0:00
20008526    7/3/2013 0:00   7/18/2013 0:00
20008526    7/3/2013 0:00   7/18/2013 0:00
20008534    3/25/2014 0:00  5/5/2014 0:00
20008534    3/25/2014 0:00  5/5/2014 0:00
20008534    3/25/2014 0:00  5/5/2014 0:00
20008534    3/25/2014 0:00  5/5/2014 0:00
20008534    3/25/2014 0:00  5/5/2014 0:00
20008534    3/25/2014 0:00  5/5/2014 0:00
20008534    3/25/2014 0:00  5/5/2014 0:00
20008534    3/25/2014 0:00  5/5/2014 0:00
20008534    3/25/2014 0:00  5/5/2014 0:00
20008534    3/25/2014 0:00  5/5/2014 0:00
20008534    3/25/2014 0:00  5/5/2014 0:00
20008534    3/25/2014 0:00  5/5/2014 0:00
20008534    3/25/2014 0:00  5/5/2014 0:00
20008636    7/15/2015 0:00  8/18/2015 0:00
20008636    7/15/2015 0:00  8/18/2015 0:00
20008636    7/15/2015 0:00  8/18/2015 0:00
```

Basically, I want see if both dates are within my designated time period.

```
period_beg = datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 1, 0, 0)
period_end = datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 30, 0, 0)
```

Here is where I am going, but this seems crazy and convoluted... Ohh and it doesnt work! lol.

```
df['TimeCheck'] = df[(df['First_Date'] >= period_beg) and (df['Last_Date'] <= period_end)]
```

Here is what I am looking to obtain:

```
Num         First_Date      Last_Date       TimeCheck
20008526    7/3/2013 0:00   7/18/2013 0:00  TRUE
20008526    7/3/2013 0:00   7/18/2013 0:00  TRUE
20008526    7/3/2013 0:00   7/18/2013 0:00  TRUE
20008526    7/3/2013 0:00   7/18/2013 0:00  TRUE
20008526    7/3/2013 0:00   7/18/2013 0:00  TRUE
20008526    7/3/2013 0:00   7/18/2013 0:00  TRUE
20008526    7/3/2013 0:00   7/18/2013 0:00  TRUE
20008526    7/3/2013 0:00   7/18/2013 0:00  TRUE
20008526    7/3/2013 0:00   7/18/2013 0:00  TRUE
20008526    7/3/2013 0:00   7/18/2013 0:00  TRUE
20008526    7/3/2013 0:00   7/18/2013 0:00  TRUE
20008526    7/3/2013 0:00   7/18/2013 0:00  TRUE
20008526    7/3/2013 0:00   7/18/2013 0:00  TRUE
20008534    3/25/2014 0:00  5/5/2014 0:00   FALSE
20008534    3/25/2014 0:00  5/5/2014 0:00   FALSE
20008534    3/25/2014 0:00  5/5/2014 0:00   FALSE
20008534    3/25/2014 0:00  5/5/2014 0:00   FALSE
20008534    3/25/2014 0:00  5/5/2014 0:00   FALSE
20008534    3/25/2014 0:00  5/5/2014 0:00   FALSE
20008534    3/25/2014 0:00  5/5/2014 0:00   FALSE
20008534    3/25/2014 0:00  5/5/2014 0:00   FALSE
20008534    3/25/2014 0:00  5/5/2014 0:00   FALSE
20008534    3/25/2014 0:00  5/5/2014 0:00   FALSE
20008534    3/25/2014 0:00  5/5/2014 0:00   FALSE
20008534    3/25/2014 0:00  5/5/2014 0:00   FALSE
20008534    3/25/2014 0:00  5/5/2014 0:00   FALSE
20008636    7/15/2015 0:00  8/18/2015 0:00  TRUE
20008636    7/15/2015 0:00  8/18/2015 0:00  TRUE
20008636    7/15/2015 0:00  8/18/2015 0:00  TRUE
```

So thoughts on how this should be done?  Also - should I be doing this in this fashion (I dont know the term for it) or should I be iterating through the rows and adding the value one-by-one?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use bitwise `&` instead of `and`:

```
In [7]:
period_beg = dt.datetime(2015, 7, 1, 0, 0)
period_end = dt.datetime(2015, 9, 30, 0, 0)
df['TimeCheck'] = (df['First_Date'] >= period_beg) & (df['Last_Date'] <= period_end)
df

Out[7]:
         Num First_Date  Last_Date TimeCheck
0   20008526 2013-07-03 2013-07-18     False
1   20008526 2013-07-03 2013-07-18     False
2   20008526 2013-07-03 2013-07-18     False
3   20008526 2013-07-03 2013-07-18     False
4   20008526 2013-07-03 2013-07-18     False
5   20008526 2013-07-03 2013-07-18     False
6   20008526 2013-07-03 2013-07-18     False
7   20008526 2013-07-03 2013-07-18     False
8   20008526 2013-07-03 2013-07-18     False
9   20008526 2013-07-03 2013-07-18     False
10  20008526 2013-07-03 2013-07-18     False
11  20008526 2013-07-03 2013-07-18     False
12  20008526 2013-07-03 2013-07-18     False
13  20008534 2014-03-25 2014-05-05     False
14  20008534 2014-03-25 2014-05-05     False
15  20008534 2014-03-25 2014-05-05     False
16  20008534 2014-03-25 2014-05-05     False
17  20008534 2014-03-25 2014-05-05     False
18  20008534 2014-03-25 2014-05-05     False
19  20008534 2014-03-25 2014-05-05     False
20  20008534 2014-03-25 2014-05-05     False
21  20008534 2014-03-25 2014-05-05     False
22  20008534 2014-03-25 2014-05-05     False
23  20008534 2014-03-25 2014-05-05     False
24  20008534 2014-03-25 2014-05-05     False
25  20008534 2014-03-25 2014-05-05     False
26  20008636 2015-07-15 2015-08-18      True
27  20008636 2015-07-15 2015-08-18      True
28  20008636 2015-07-15 2015-08-18      True
```

this is because you're comparing arrays, not scalar values which `and` doesn't understand.

Also you're trying to use the boolean mask from the condition to index the df by doing this:

```
df['TimeCheck'] = df[(df['First_Date'] >= period_beg) and (df['Last_Date'] <= period_end)]
```

which because of the `and` generates a `ValueError`:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Even if you changed the `and` to `&` in the above this will only assign the `True` values:

```
In [10]:
df['TimeCheck'] = df[(df['First_Date'] >= period_beg) & (df['Last_Date'] <= period_end)]
df

Out[10]:
         Num First_Date  Last_Date    TimeCheck
0   20008526 2013-07-03 2013-07-18          NaN
1   20008526 2013-07-03 2013-07-18          NaN
2   20008526 2013-07-03 2013-07-18          NaN
3   20008526 2013-07-03 2013-07-18          NaN
4   20008526 2013-07-03 2013-07-18          NaN
5   20008526 2013-07-03 2013-07-18          NaN
6   20008526 2013-07-03 2013-07-18          NaN
7   20008526 2013-07-03 2013-07-18          NaN
8   20008526 2013-07-03 2013-07-18          NaN
9   20008526 2013-07-03 2013-07-18          NaN
10  20008526 2013-07-03 2013-07-18          NaN
11  20008526 2013-07-03 2013-07-18          NaN
12  20008526 2013-07-03 2013-07-18          NaN
13  20008534 2014-03-25 2014-05-05          NaN
14  20008534 2014-03-25 2014-05-05          NaN
15  20008534 2014-03-25 2014-05-05          NaN
16  20008534 2014-03-25 2014-05-05          NaN
17  20008534 2014-03-25 2014-05-05          NaN
18  20008534 2014-03-25 2014-05-05          NaN
19  20008534 2014-03-25 2014-05-05          NaN
20  20008534 2014-03-25 2014-05-05          NaN
21  20008534 2014-03-25 2014-05-05          NaN
22  20008534 2014-03-25 2014-05-05          NaN
23  20008534 2014-03-25 2014-05-05          NaN
24  20008534 2014-03-25 2014-05-05          NaN
25  20008534 2014-03-25 2014-05-05          NaN
26  20008636 2015-07-15 2015-08-18  2.00086e+07
27  20008636 2015-07-15 2015-08-18  2.00086e+07
28  20008636 2015-07-15 2015-08-18  2.00086e+07
```

Which is not what you want

Also only the last 3 rows meet your condition, not sure why you expect the rows with last date value: `7/18/2013 0:00` to also be `True`